# How to write a batch file to check for specifed folders in a directory

Tags: file, batch-file

How can I write a batch file to check for specified subfolders in a directory and then generate a log file showing the results of the findings (found it or not found). I am new to scripting and below is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
ECHO
SET /P QUESTION="Perform file check (Y/N)?"
if QUESTION == y goto :START_SCRIPT 

:START_SCRIPT
if exist "C:\Folder\ABC" (echo found it) else echo not found;

if exist "C:\Folder\DEF" (echo found it) else echo not found;

if exist "C:\Folder\GHI" (echo found it) else echo not found;

test.bat >> out.txt
```

Comment: Should the `echo` messages be individualized to report which files are found or not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more

```
@echo off
    set "folder=c:\folder"

(   for %%d in ("ABC" "DEF" "GHI") do if exist "%folder%\%%~d" (
        echo "%%~d" found
    ) else (
        echo "%%~d" not found
    )
) >> file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple;

```
@echo off
choice /m "Perform Check?"
if errorlevel 2 Exit

:loop
set /p query="Folder Name: "
if "%query%"=="" goto :end
if exist "C:\Folder\%query%" (Echo %query% Exists&Echo %query% Found >> out.txt
) Else (
Echo %query% Doesn't Exist&Echo %query% Not Found >> out.txt
)
goto :loop
:end
Echo End of Batch File&sleep 5
Exit
```

And that should do what you want (note it requires user input) which if is not the case, can use a log file redirected as input.

Mona

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
call :FolderExists abc && Echo Yes || Echo No
exit /b

:FolderExists folder
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do (
  if /i %%a EQU %1 exit /b 0)
exit /b 1
```